# How do I find the name of the top student in an array list?

Tags: java

I am studying Java and have been asked to produce methods that can be used in order to gather statistics based off of the student names and marks that are entered. I have worked out how to calculate the top mark but what I need to do is return the name of the student that got the highest mark, how would I do this? I was thinking I could try to return the string before the highest int but I wasn't sure how I would do that.

Edit: Just to make it clear, currently, when END is entered in to the console following the input of data, the top mark is returned - I need to return the mark of the best student.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Course {
    private ArrayList<Student> people = new ArrayList<Student>();
    private int passing = 0;
    private int failing = 0;
    private int top = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    private int sum = 0;

    public void add( Student student ) {
        people.add( student );
        if(student.getMark() >= 40){
            passing++;
        }
        else {
            failing++;
        }
        sum += student.getMark();
        if(student.getMark() > top) {
            top = student.getMark();
        }
    }

    public int pass() {
        return passing;
    }

    public int fail() {
        return failing;
    }

    public int top() {
        return top;
    }

    public double average() {
        return sum / people.size();
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Update: BinaryJudy, I did what you said but I get a 'NoSuchMethod' error for the top name, this is what I changed my code to:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Course {
    private ArrayList<Student> people = new ArrayList<Student>();
    private int passing = 0;
    private int failing = 0;
    private int top = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    private int sum = 0;
    private String topName;

    public void add( Student student ) {
        people.add( student );
        if(student.getMark() >= 40){
            passing++;
        }
        else {
            failing++;
        }
        sum += student.getMark();
        if(student.getMark() > top) {
            top = student.getMark();
        }

        if(student.getMark() > top) {
            top = student.getMark();
            topName = student.getName();
        }
    }

    public int pass() {
        return passing;
    }

    public int fail() {
        return failing;
    }

    public String top() {
        return topName;
    }

    public double average() {
        return sum / people.size();
    }
}
```

Any idea why? :)

Comment: Iterate through ArrayList and find the one with the highest. That will be the most basic way. You can also keep a count of the highest when you are adding elements to the ArrayList as well. Or sort the ArrayList by marks and get the highest in O(1).

Answer (score 1):

You have already found the student with the top mark. Update the top name with the name of the student when the top mark is found. Finding the top mark results in also finding the name.

```
String topName;

 if(student.getMark() > top) {
        top = student.getMark();
        topName = student.getName();
    }
```

Comment: I tried to do what you said but had problems, can you please read the update of my post? Thank you :)

Comment: The output has to be in this format:     System.out.println("Top student      = " + ci101.top() );

Comment: In your code above you have the same check for top mark twice. You only needed to add the one line (topName = student.getName();) and the variable (String topName;) for the name.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! I have one other small problem now in that the average isn't quite correct, for example where the answer should be 70.50 it is displayed as 70.0, any idea why? :)

Comment: Nevermind I think I got it, I changed sum from an int to a double

Answer (score 0):

Note that you're storing a bunch of students who I assume each have a mark for the course. All you need to do is cycle through that Arraylist, and find out who has the highest mark, and return that student.

Something like this may work for you:

```
public String topStu(ArrayList<Student> list) { // take in any list of students
    int topStudentScore = 0; // default value
    Student topStudent = null;
    for (student x : list) { // cycle through all students in the list
        if (x.getMark() > topStudentScore) { // if the score is higher than the current listed score
            topStudentScore = x.getMark(); // update the top score
            topStudent = x; // update top student
        }
    }
    return topStudent.getName(); // return his name
}
```

You can easily write this to be a function for a specific course - you can remove the parameter, and directly access the private ArrayList if you want to.

Alternatively, you can write the above function to be a static function that takes any list of students from any course.

Comment: I have another class that has public String getName()
  {
     return name;
  }

Answer (score 0):

If a student is unique in the `people` list and insert order has no importance, then you can change

```
ArrayList<Student> people = ...;
```

By

```
// Java7 and before
SortedSet<Student> people = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<Student>() {
    public int compare(Student s1, Student s2) {
        return s2.getMark()-s1.getMark();  // sorted by decreasing mark
    }
});

// Java8
SortedSet<Student> people 
    = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getMark).reversed());
```

Then finding the top student is matter of getting the first from the `people` set:

```
Student top = people.first();
```

As a bonus, you can compute easily the ranking for all student. Adding new student will put them at the right ranking.

Note: Be aware that modifying a student mark *after* insertion will not change automatically its ranking and should be handled through a sequence of :

```
Student s = ...;
people.remove(s);
s.setMark(42);
people.add(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Classroom
{
    Student[] students;
    int numStudentsAdded;



    public Classroom(int numStudents)
    {
        students = new Student[numStudents];
        numStudentsAdded = 0;
    }

    public Student getTopStudent()
    {
        int y = 0;

            //have to use numStudentsAdded

            for ( int i = 0 ; i < numStudentsAdded ; i++)
            {
                if (students[y].getAverageScore() < students[i].getAverageScore())
                {
                    y = i;
                }
            }

        return students[y] ;
    } 

    public void addStudent(Student s)
    {
        students[numStudentsAdded] = s;
        numStudentsAdded++;
    }

    public void printStudents()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < numStudentsAdded; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(students[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation around code to make it useful to future readers?